# GS Named Function Not Accepting Named Function Output as Input

Tags: google-sheets, named-function

## Introduction

I'm trying to create custom Google Sheets functions for tabletop rolls and rules, and I ran into what appears to be a technical limitation on part of Google Sheets new Named Functions feature, but I'm hoping to be wrong and hope the community here can recognize a mistake of mine or recommend a sensible workaround<sup>**1**</sup>.

For whatever reason, it appears that Google Sheets' new Named Functions do not accept output from other named functions as input.

I have made an [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bYCY34yJx5tQovuiUnUHbVcFKksrxUpN0s4tKUCwiG0/edit?usp=sharing) with a demonstration as well as a testing zone that the community is free to mess around with.

---

## The Problem

I am working with two named functions that I have created:

### FUNCTION `=ROLL_D10(count)`

- `count`: The number of dice rolls you want to roll. Default: 1
- `=ARRAYFORMULA(ROUNDUP(RANDARRAY(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(count),count=INT(count),count>=1),count,1),1)*10,0))`

### FUNCTION `=ROLL_ADVANTAGE(rolls)`

- `rolls`: A singular cell or array of cells consisting of numerical rolls.
- `=IFERROR(LARGE(rolls,1),NA())`

The goal is to be able to nest the named functions like so: `=ROLL_ADVANTAGE(ROLL_D10(3))`
The result should be to retrieve the highest value from a 3d10 roll. To those familiar with tabletop, this would be a double advantage roll.

What appears to be happening is that once created, the nested function will not recalculate unless the cell that contains the nested formula is changed. For example, if I change `=ROLL_ADVANTAGE(ROLL_D10(3))` to `=ROLL_ADVANTAGE(ROLL_D10(3))&"A"`, it will recalculate the `ROLL_D10` function. It will not recalculate if any other On Change or Every Minute/Every Hour event is triggered.

---

## Tests Performed

I have tested the following methods and achieved the following results. Again I invite users to see the [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bYCY34yJx5tQovuiUnUHbVcFKksrxUpN0s4tKUCwiG0/edit?usp=sharing) for live examples.

- **r** = Non-named `ROLL_D10` function; **R** = Named `ROLL_D10` function.
- **a** = Non-named `ADVANTAGE` function; **A** = Named `ADVANTAGE` function.
- **:S** = Output posted to the sheet prior to being passed as input.
- **:ƒ** = Output passed directly as formula input.
- **.n** = Non-named function; **.N** = Named function.
- ‘⇒’ Output passed from `ROLL_D10` to `ADVANTAGE` function.

| Tested Operation | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `r:S` *…Raw formula* | Success |
| `R:S` *…Raw formula* | Success |
| `a:S` *…Raw formula* | Success |
| `A:S` *…Raw formula* | Success |
| `r:ƒ` *…Raw formula* | Success |
| `R:ƒ` *…Raw formula* | Possibly does not work with `ƒ.N ⇒ f.N` |
| `a:ƒ` *…Raw formula* | Success |
| `A:ƒ` *…Raw formula* | Success |
| `r:S ⇒ a` | Success |
| `r:S ⇒ A` | Success |
| `R:S ⇒ a` | Success |
| `R:S ⇒ A` | Success |
| `r:ƒ ⇒ a` | Success |
| `r:ƒ ⇒ A` | Success |
| `R:ƒ ⇒ a` | Success |
| `R:ƒ ⇒ A` | FAILURE |

---

## Annotations

1. I consider a sensible workaround to be avoiding integrating advantage/disadvantage/neutral arguments into the roll functions as this increases complexity and therefore makes it less user-friendly: I do hope to make these functions available generally. If this is the only reasonable option, that is fine, but I would prefer to explore other options first.

Answer (score 0):

In the formula `=ROLL_ADVANTAGE(ROLL_D10(3))`, the inner function `ROLL_D10(3)` has a single static parameter `3` that never changes. The function will not recalculate as long as the parameter remains the same. Since `ROLL_D10(3)` will always return the same result, the outer `ROLL_ADVANTAGE()` function will also return its cached result instead of recalculating.

This behavior is a side effect of the [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) used by Google Sheets to cache the return values of functions. Its purpose is to improve spreadsheet performance. As long as a function's parameters remain the same, it will return the cached result without recalculating it.

The standard recipe to make the function recalculate is to add a `dummy` parameter that *does* get changed. The signature becomes `ROLL_D10(count, dummy)`. Then modify the formula to make the dummy parameter refer to a value that gets updated with new values every now and then, such as cell `A1`, like this:

`=ROLL_ADVANTAGE(ROLL_D10(3, A1))`

Your named function does not need to actually use the dummy parameter — its mere presence is enough to avoid the memoization effect. The named function will get called every time the value in cell `A1` changes, which is not a perfect solution, but it is usually good enough for most needs. You can increment the value in cell `A1` manually, or use `=now()` there to easily force recalculation from time to time.